# How to set up diferent password rules for regular users and for root on PAM

Tags: passwords, debian, root, pam

Bear with me for a moment. I'm doing a college exercise setting up a VM and I'm having a very hard time understanding what PAM is and actually works. All the results that come on google are either too basic or too complex and I really don't know what to look up. My exercise requires me to set up a bunch of rules for both normal users and root:

*To set up a strong password policy, you have to comply with the following requirements:*

- *Your password must be at least 10 characters long.*
- *It must contain an uppercase letter and a number.*
- *It must not contain more than 3 consecutive identical characters.*
- *The password must not include the name of the user.*
- **The following rule does not apply to the root password: The password must
  have at least 7 characters that are not part of the former
  password.**
- *Of course, your root password has to comply with this policy*

I haven't been able to find any good sites that explain how PAM works in a good way however I found that for the normal user I need to edit `/etc/pam.d/common-password` with:

```
password        requisite          pam_pwquality.so retry=3 minlen=10 ucredit=-1 dcredit=-1 maxrepeat=3 reject_username difok=7 enforce_for_root
```

Although I don't understand how PAM works I do understand it's flags.
My question is how do I set up different rules for root?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Note that root is not asked for an old password so the checks that compare the old and new password are not performed.](https://man.archlinux.org/man/pam_pwquality.8#enforce_for_root)
So, basically, the phrase

> The following rule does not apply to the root password

means you *can't* make `difok=7` work for root and *not* that you *must* create a separate rule for root.